# How to set up language in meteor angularjs ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs, meteor, calendar, fullcalendar, lang

I'm trying to set up ui-calendar with meteor and change the language but nothing appends in the calendar. What I did is this :

```
meteor add planettraining:jquery-fullcalendar

meteor add angularui:ui-calendar
```

In my view :

```
<div ui-calendar="vm.calendarConfig" ng-model="vm.eventSources" calendar="calendar"></div>
```

In my controller :

```
vm.calendarConfig = {
            lang: 'fr',
            contentHeight: 'auto',
            selectable: true,
            editable: true,
}
```

With this only the header is set up in french but not inside the calendar.

So I push a package with the lang file from fullcalendar

```
bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/lang/fr.js
```

pull the package in my project but nothing change.

I also try to set up angular with ngLocale but again nothing works.

Maybe I don't do it properly.

I someone has any clues on that it would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around

```
vm.calendarConfig = {
   monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin','Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam', 'Dim'],
   axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
   timeFormat: {
      agenda: 'H:mm',
      month: 'H:mm'
   }
}
```

But unfortunately nothing to do with languages...